# Paragraph auto newline

Tags: css, html, text

In DIV I put paragraph but when text is longer then div,it does not make new line but out of the DIV.I try with:  `-moz-hyphens:auto; -ms-hyphens:auto; -webkit-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; word-wrap:break-word;` but it doesn't work.Any suggestions?

Here is code of div:

```
<div id="content">
<p id="test">tfufygigighfetefddddddddddddsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
```

css code of div:

```
#content {
float:left;
position:absolute;
background-color:#D4D3D0;
height:500px;
width:80%;
}
```

and the css of paragraph:

```
p.test {
-moz-hyphens:auto;
-ms-hyphens:auto;
-webkit-hyphens:auto;
hyphens:auto;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm going out on a limb here! But I believe you need to put `word-wrap: break-word;` in the div css, instead of the `<p>` css. It works for me!

Edit:

Oh wait, I can see what you did wrong. The name of the `<p>` tag isn't `p.test` it's `#test`!

Comment: For people who see it now. It seems word-wrap has been changed to overflow-wrap, so the code would be: overflow-wrap:break-word; See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap for more info.

Answer (score 7):

add `word-wrap: break-word;` to `#content`

You can also remove those styles from your `p` element.

Comment: Thank you Scott,I fix the problem :) @JBARNETT,thanks for you too,this work too! :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add this two line in #content

```
#content{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print each sentence in each line, without `<br>`

```
<p style="font-family:courier;white-space: pre;">
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
</p>
```

For example check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/muthupandiant/sgp8rjfs/